# Cordova InAppBrowser plugin shows blank screen on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I've done some serious searching on stackoverflow, but no result. A lot of similar issues, but no one has the solution that I need.

My problem is: I'm developing a ios cordova app that make use of the InAppBrowser plugin.

Whenever I run the app from xcode directly on my iPhone, it works fine.

Whenever I run the app from xcode in a simulator on my mac, it works fine.

Whenever I upload the package to the appstore and run the app through Testflight however, the InAppBrowser opens, but only shows a white screen with a Done button at the bottom (but no error messages). And I have no clue how to debug this.

I've already made several changes to the Content Security Policy, I already tried making changes to config.xml (`<allow-intent>`, `<allow navigation>`, `<access origin="*" />`), but nothing changes.

I'm using cordova ios 5.0.0, InAppBrowser 3.0.0, Cordova 9.0.0

A good suggestion, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the entire project with a clean environment, added the ios platform again, added all the plugins again, copied my html/css/js files back and now it works. Probably there was a misalignment somewhere between cordova / platform / plugins.
Funny though, that it worked locally and in a simulator, but not in Testflight and production.