# Error -Ionic InAppBrowser on iOS Loading White Blank Screen

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, inappbrowser

I am getting the white blank screen in ios cordova application after injecting inAppBrowser dependency in one of the components.

I couldnt resolve the issue. Kindly help

Comment: Make sure you're using the WKWebView: https://ionicframework.com/blog/wkwebview-for-all-a-new-webview-for-ionic/ also read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55983123/cordova-inappbrowser-plugin-shows-blank-screen-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

Instead of injecting InAppbrowser in constructor,
use
cordova.InAppBrowser.open in ur calling method.

This solves the problem.

Please find the url for the same,
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-open-link-externally/83880/20